# Access router through public IP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I need to access my router through its public IP address , but there's a port forwarding role that forward all HTTP requests port(80) to an internal server .

I just need to access the router itself to configure some thing .

is there any way to access the router it self without forwarding me to the internal server ?

router model : huawei b315

Comment: Some can.  Please [edit] your question to include details of your router

Comment: my router is huawei b315

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an easily accessible online manual. Can you provide a screenshot of your 'Settings -> System' tab from the web administration?

Comment: Turn off the port forwarding from the internal network.

Comment: can i do it remotely ?

Comment: "_can i do it remotely ?_" - hopefully not, that would be a significant security risk. You'll need to do the initial configuration for remote access from the internal network.

Answer (score 1):

To remotely configure it without having the traffic forwarded you would need to use an alternate port to gain access.

If the B315 has already been configured to allow SSH/Telnet you may be able to get access that way in the form of a command line and configure it from there, or delete the forward and then access it normally over HTTP. If these are off you ned to access it from within the LAN (remote desktop to a local PC would work if you have something like teamviewer setup).